# android : error getting tabview app crash

Tags: android, android-intent, tabs, android-tabhost

i have android app where i get a string from previous activity and transfer it to next activity.
works fine when i do it with one tab . but when i specify it for the second tab the app crashes

error in log cat  you must specify a way to create the tab indicator.

code   **Solved**

```
 package com.example.pms;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;






public class TabControl extends TabActivity 
{
    public static TabControl mTabControl;
    public static TextView textView;
    public static TabHost tabHost ;
    final Context context = this;
    //public static String strEmployeeID = "";
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        Resources resources = getResources(); 
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); 




          Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
          String strEmployeeID="";
         TabSpec photospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Hourly entry");
            // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
            photospec.setIndicator("Hourly Entry");

              if (extras != null)
              {

                  String value = extras.getString("new_variable_name");
//                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),  value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  strEmployeeID = value;
              }


             Intent photosIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HourlyEntry.class);
             photosIntent.putExtra("new_variable_name",strEmployeeID);
             photospec.setContent(photosIntent);



             TabSpec photospec1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Leave app");
                // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
                photospec1.setIndicator("Leave App");

                  if (extras != null)
                  {

                      String value = extras.getString("new_variable_name");
//                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),  value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      strEmployeeID = value;
                  }


                 Intent photosIntent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LeaveApp.class);
                 photosIntent1.putExtra("new_variable_name",strEmployeeID);
                 photospec1.setContent(photosIntent1);


        tabHost.addTab(photospec);
        tabHost.addTab(photospec1);



        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

    }


}
```

Comment: did you add LeaveApp,HourlyEntry to Manifiest?

Comment: post your logcat then.

Comment: yes... i will just post my log cat

Comment: posted my log vat pls see

Comment: here your both Tab names are same like `TabSpec photospec1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Photos");` and `TabSpec photospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Photos");`  change name and try

Comment: solved your issue or not?

Comment: trying something.....

Comment: Sir is there a way that whenever i select the other tab the previous tab gets reset.. i want the tab to load its content again from starting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
    TabSpec photospec1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Photos");
      // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
    photospec.setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_home));
```

With

```
     TabSpec photospec1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Photos2");
            // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
     photospec1.setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_home));
      if (extras != null)

              {
                  String value = extras.getString("new_variable_name");
                  strEmployeeID = value;
              }

         Intent photosIntent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LeaveApp.class);
         photosIntent1.putExtra("new_variable_name",strEmployeeID);
         photospec1.setContent(photosIntent1);
```

And your issue is here you never set `Tab Indicator` to Second tab **correct** like below

```
  photospec1.setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_home));
```

And also your issue is here you set wrong `set Content Intent` to Second tab **correct** like below:

```
    Intent photosIntent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LeaveApp.class);
    photosIntent1.putExtra("new_variable_name",strEmployeeID);
    photospec1.setContent(photosIntent1);
```